# Подскажите, как сохранить полученное значение egg и продолжить цикл именно с полученным значением

Tags: python

```
hp = input("hp: ")
while True:
    dam = input("damage: ")
    egg = int(hp) - int(dam)
    if egg <= 0:
        print('враг повержен')
        break
    else:
        print('оставшееся здоровье:',egg)
        continue
```

Хотелось бы что бы после continue код не просто вычитал dam из изначального hp, а  именно продолжал взаимодействия с уже полученными данными из egg

Comment: Напишите `egg = 0` перед циклом и используйте внутри *while* как хотите. И уберите *continue*, как последняя инструкция в цикле он бесполезен

Comment: Если в данном куске кода везде `egg` банально заменить на `hp`, то даже в таком виде заработает.